# Is it possible to use Linux terminals like Xterm and Xfce4-terminal as IntelliJ terminals?

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I would like the execution output in IntelliJ to be executed in a transparent console/terminal, and since that's not possible on the default IntelliJ terminal I would like to use Ubuntu terminals to display my programs output, so is it possible to use those terminals like the XFCE terminal as IntelliJ terminals? Thank you so much all!

I tried to use Ubuntu terminal as XFCE terminal but I didn't succeed...

Answer (score 0):

If the desired terminal has a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=androidstudio&products=appcode&products=aqua&products=clion&products=dataspell&products=dbe&products=go&products=idea&products=idea_ce&products=mps&products=phpstorm&products=pycharm&products=pycharm_ce&products=rider&products=ruby&products=rust&products=webstorm&search=terminal) in JetBrains Marketplace, then it's possible.

XTerm and XFCE4-terminal are not in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, how do I check the list please?

Comment: Look for your terminal name in the linked list of terminal plugins